# Выполнить submit при checked recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Как автоматически отправить форму (выполнить submit), если галочка "Я не робот" установлена?

Comment: Можно попробовать на JS написать функцию ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: т.е вы хотите отправить форму как только пользователь установит галочку?

Comment: да, как только "Я не робот" будет установлена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я обычно использую возможность `data-callback`:

```
    <script>
      var yourCallBackFunction = function() {
        console("Галочка установлена");
 /*
 отправляете вашу форму
*/
      };
    </script>

    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="yourCallBackFunction" data-sitekey="YOUR_KEY"></div>
```